button on image with grids(Flutter)
im trying to make an image into multiple grids like one image into 9 equal parts or anything based on the shape of a door or a model of a door but the problem is i'm not understanding how to add a button over that and when i click on it,different dropdown should open for every single image grid and doing this using flutter.Please help me.Thank you
i tried using html still a lot of errors so just give a sample code

Assuming that you already have the widgets that contains the images, you just need to wrap them in a InkWell, like this:
class ImageContainerButton extends StatelessWidget {
  const ImageContainerButton({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    void onTap(){
      // Your code here
    }

    return InkWell(
      onTap: onTap,
      child: Container(
        child: // Your Image here,
      ),
    );
  }
}

